# Parser Generator: How to use GPLEX and GPPG together?

Tags: c#, parsing, gppg

After looking through posts for good C# parser generators, I stumbled across GPLEX and GPPG.  I'd like to use GPLEX to generate tokens for GPPG to parse and create a tree (similar to the lex/yacc relationship).  However, I can't seem to find an example on how these two interact together.  With lex/yacc, lex returns tokens that are defined by yacc, and can store values in yylval.  How is this done in GPLEX/GPPG (it is missing from their documentation)?

Attached is the lex code I would like to convert over to GPLEX:

```
%{
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[Oo][Rr]                return OR;
[Aa][Nn][Dd]            return AND;
[Nn][Oo][Tt]            return NOT;
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*   yylval=yytext; return ID;
%%
```

Thanks!
Andrew

Comment: Do you have any code to start off with? I haven't played with it in years but I'm pretty sure what you need to do to get them to work together is minimal. IIRC, it's just a matter of making sure you have the right namespaces in scope (or define both the yacc/lex files in the same namespace) and possibly the token class name and assume everything is generated in the other.

Comment: No code for GPLEX, but I have the equivalent grammar in lex if that would help?  In yacc/lex, all you have to do is define a token in the yacc file and simply include the header file generated by yacc in the lex file.  I'm not sure what classes are actually created by GPPG when defining a token though...

Comment: @AndrewSmith: I have used it a lot in the past. Pretty easy IIRC. They have a simple sample in the zip. Else have a look at mine in IronScheme @ https://github.com/leppie/IronScheme/tree/master/IronScheme/IronScheme/Compiler (there are 2 sets of lexer/parsers there).

Comment: @leppie: I take it all I need from here is the .y and the .lex files?  This is great!  Probably more complexity than I'll need, but it definitely answers my question.

Comment: @AndrewSmith: Yes. I dont recall making any modifications impacting the syntax of either of those files.

Answer (score 4):

First: include the reference "QUT.ShiftReduceParser.dll" in your Project. It is provided in the download-package from GPLEX.

Sample-Code for Main-Program:

```
using System;
using ....;
using QUT.Gppg;
using Scanner;
using Parser;

namespace NCParser
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pathTXT = @"C:\temp\testFile.txt";
        FileStream file = new FileStream(pathTXT, FileMode.Open);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
        scanner.SetSource(file, 0);
        Parser parser = new Parser(scanner);            
    }
}
}
```

Sample-Code for GPLEX:

```
%using Parser;           //include the namespace of the generated Parser-class
%namespace Scanner       //names the Namespace of the generated Scanner-class
%visibility public       //visibility of the types "Tokens","ScanBase","Scanner"
%scannertype Scanner     //names the Scannerclass to "Scanner"
%scanbasetype ScanBase   //names the Scanbaseclass to "ScanBase"
%tokentype Tokens        //names the Tokenenumeration to "Tokens"

%option codePage:65001 out:Scanner.cs /*see the documentation of GPLEX for further Options you can use */

%{ //user-specified code will be copied in the Output-file
%}

OR [Oo][Rr]
AND [Aa][Nn][Dd]
Identifier [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*

%% //Rules Section
%{ //user-code that will be executed before getting the next token
%}

{OR}           {return (int)Tokens.kwOR;}
{AND}          {return (int)Tokens.kwAND;}
{Identifier}   {yylval = yytext; return (int)Tokens.ID;}

%% //User-code Section
```

Sample-Code for GPPG-input-file:

```
%using Scanner      //include the Namespace of the scanner-class
%output=Parser.cs   //names the output-file
%namespace Parser  //names the namespace of the Parser-class

%parsertype Parser      //names the Parserclass to "Parser"
%scanbasetype ScanBase  //names the ScanBaseclass to "ScanBase"
%tokentype Tokens       //names the Tokensenumeration to "Tokens"

%token kwAND "AND", kwOR "OR" //the received Tokens from GPLEX
%token ID

%% //Grammar Rules Section

program  : /* nothing */
         | Statements
         ;

Statements : EXPR "AND" EXPR
           | EXPR "OR" EXPR
           ;

EXPR : ID
     ;

%% //User-code Section
// Don't forget to declare the Parser-Constructor
public Parser(Scanner scnr) : base(scnr) { }
```

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)[parse](/questions/tagged/parse)[gppg](/questions/tagged/gppg)[gplex](/questions/tagged/gplex)

Comment: In the main program, don't you need too call `parser.Parse()`?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue - not knowing how to use my output from GPLEX with GPPG due to an apparent lack of documentation.  I think the problem stems from the fact that the GPLEX distribution includes gppg.exe along with gplex.exe, but only documentation for GPLEX.

If you go the GPPG homepage and download that distribution, you'll get the documentation for GPPG, which describes the requirements for the input file, how to construct your grammar, etc.  Oh, and you'll also get both binaries again - gppg.exe and gplex.exe.

It almost seems like it would be simpler to just include everything in one package.  It could definitely clear up some confusion, especially for those who may be new to lexical analysis (tokenization) and parsing (and may not be 100% familiar yet with the differences between the two).

So anyways, for those who may doing this for the first time:

**GPLEX** http://gplex.codeplex.com - used for tokenization/scanning/lexical analysis (same thing)

**GPPG** http://gppg.codeplex.com/  - takes output from a tokenizer as input to parse. For example, parsers use grammars and can do things a simple tokenizer cannot, like detect whether sets of parentheses match up.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I have had the same need of using both GPLEX and GPPG together and for making the job much more easier I have created a nuget package for using GPPG and GPLEX together in Visual Studio.
This package can be installed in C# projects based on .Net Framework and adds some command-lets to the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio. This command-lets help you in configuring the C# project for integrating GPPG and GPLEX in the build process. Essentially in your project you will edit YACC and LEX files as source code and during the build of the project, the parser and the scanner will be generated. In addition the command-lets add to the projects the files needed for customizing the parser and the scanner.

You can find it here: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/YaccLexTools/

And here is a link to the blog post that explains how to use it: 
http://ecianciotta-en.abriom.com/2013/08/yacclex-tools-v02.html

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: If it wasn't clear from the answer, this tool (YaccLexTools) generats the `.y` and `.lex` files for you such that they work together. All you need to do is write the scanner and parser rules and the rest is handled by the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx)? (This isn't a proper answer but I don't have enough reputation to post this as a comment)

Answer (score 0):

Irony, because when I jumped into parsers in C# I started exactly from those 2 tools (about a year ago). Then lexer has tiny bug (easy to fix):

- http://gplex.codeplex.com/workitem/11308

but parser had more severe:

- http://gppg.codeplex.com/workitem/11344

Lexer should be fixed (release date is June 2013), but parser **probably** still has this bug (May 2012).

So I wrote my own suite :-) https://sourceforge.net/projects/naivelangtools/ and use and develop it since then.

Your example translates (in NLT) to:

```
/[Oo][Rr]/                -> OR;
/[Aa][Nn][Dd]/            -> AND;
/[Nn][Oo][Tt]/            -> NOT;
// by default text is returned as value
/[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*/   -> ID;
```

Entire suite is similar to lex/yacc, when possible it does not rely on side effects (so you return appropriate value).